# Raw TCP Listen Socket on Cloud or Web Server

Tags: python, sockets, heroku, tcp, amazon-ec2

I have hardware that connects to raw TCP socket on any given IP and port combination. It then continually sends characters. The following piece of Python code may give you an idea of what the hardware does.

```
import socket

serverIP = '*server IP or domain*'
serverPort = 60000

Sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
Sock.connect((serverIP, serverPort))
while (1):
f = open ("send-data.txt","r")
while 1:
    c = f.readline()
    if not c:
        break
Sock.send(c + '\n')

Sock.shutdown(0)
Sock.close()
```

When this code is run it exactly behaves like my hardware system. The `send-data.txt` file contains characters similar to what hardware sends.

I have written a socket server in Python using `SocketServer` library. It allows connections, receives character stream, and stores it into a local (newly created) file. Currently, I am running this code on my system, as `localhost` and it works. I would like to serve these files through a webpage.

I want to be able to do the same on remote server. As you can see, my hardware limits me to use only raw TCP sockets. From what I understand, I'll need low-level access to the server machine like IaaS. I tried [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com), but I guess they don't allow simple python sockets. Heroku also requires you to write a web app, and I don't know how to go about that or whether it'll work with my hardware.

What hosting/Cloud solution out there could act as above-mentioned socket server and also as HTTP server which would later serve these files and webpages.

Comment: It will be ideal if your suggested server could run my already written Python Socket server.

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here, just to confirm OP is right, we don't support arbitrary socket servers.  (yet?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd like to know which affordable hosting solution would allow you to communicate via arbitrary TCP sockets.

The answer is simple: Pretty much any VPS (Virtual Private Server) company or IaaS provider. Since you tagged your question with Amazon-EC2, yes they do too, but the learning curve to get your first instance running and the security groups (read: firewall rules, which live outside your VM) configured, is rather steep. That said, you do have a so-called "Free Tier" there for one year, which enables you to try out most of their services free-of-charge.

Other providers might be more suitable. (I'm not sure if it's allowed to suggest providers here, but you could for example look at Linode or Rackspace Cloud; they offer much less flexibility than EC2, but it's  a whole lot easier to get started.)

As with any IaaS option, it would be beneficial to know Linux, networking and some security basics (at the very least) as you will be solely responsible for the things you create.

Talking about security...

If that piece of code you posted has a similarly rudimentary receiving end, you're setting yourself up for trouble as soon as it's out there in public, as the communication is done in plain text [*] and doesn't seem to require any kind of authentication. Anybody could probably telnet to the receiving end and just inject some lines of text?

(That's exactly why considerably sane PaaS providers often don't let you communicate over arbitrary ports and sockets :-) )

[*] I am guessing that, because you use readline. If any encryption was involved, you'd likely write/read in chunks of bytes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Trying out EC2 seems an attractive option, but I don't know much about it. Can I configure it as any linux-ubuntu server? At the very least, I need a stable IP address and permission to open ports.

Comment: About security: as I mentioned, the actual data (character stream) would be sent by an embedded hardware module so no encryption. My socket server makes separate connections with each requester. Are you sure anyone can add text to my already made connection simply through telnet? Plus, the data being sent is meant to be public so anybody may tap in and listen.

Comment: @Ics yes you could use an EC2 instance to run Ubuntu on it. The IP stays assigned as long as the instance is running. They put very little restrictions on how you use their infrastructure. Per default security groups are locked down, but you can easily open them up to your liking. That being said, if you have a static IP address for the clients, those security groups can come in handy to deal with the security concerns I mentioned (admittedly wild guesses, derived from the code snippet :))

Comment: Thank you for helping!!!
In your answer, you say the learning curve for EC2 is pretty steep for configuring security groups. How is that different from say, Linode? 

How do AWS map any instances' private IP to public IPs? I cannot afford the public IP to change regularly as I have to hardcode it into my hardware. Also, to make any arbitrary port accessible, would port-forwarding be required? 
I am currently looking for the easiest/quickest solution.

Comment: @Ics You're welcome! (Don't forget to mark this as an answer, if you think it qualifies as an answer :))  You can have so-called Elastic IPs, which are static IPs that make your instance accessible from outside under that IP. No port-forwarding required. Also, they don't cost anything, unless you don't actually associate them with an instance. Linode is easier to use for a beginner, who doesn't intend to automate the whole infrastructure setup through a massive API such as Amazon's. It's a few clicks and you're ready to go. They don't offer a free tier, but are fairly good value for money.

Comment: Okay! Thanks again. I'll will soon try out Amazon EC2 and Linode, and post feedback here. I am more inclined towards the easier solution (Linode) as you suggested. I am a student so I wanted some hands-on with the most widely used tech (EC2).

Comment: well doesn't look like you posted any feedback. I would really appreciate some.